# What APIs to use for program working across computers

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing

I want to try programming something which can do things across multiple end points, so that when things occur on one computer events can occur on others. Obviously the problem here is in sending commands to the other end points.

I'm just not sure of what program I would use to do this with, I'm guessing it would have to use an API which uses some kind of client server model. I expect there are things that people use to do this with but I don't know what they are called.

How would I go about doing this? Are there common APIs which allow people to do this?

Comment: How "real time" does it need to be? Does it need to be peer to peer or via a server?

Comment: Peer to peer is probably preferable but I'd like suggestions on server too please. I haven't done this before and I'd like to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two types to distinguish between: **RPC** APIs and **Message Queues** (MQ)

An **RPC-style API** can be imaged like an remotely callable interface, it typically gives you one response per request. Apache Thrift<sup>1)</sup> is one of the frameworks designed for this purpose: An easy to use cross-platform, cross-language RPC framework. (And oh yes, it also supports Erlang, just in case ...). There are a few others around, like Googles protocol buffers, Apache Avro, and a few more.

**Message Queuing** systems are more suitable in cases where a more loosely coupling is desired or acceptable. In contrast to an RPC-style framework and API, a messaging queue decouples request and response a bit more. For example, a MQ system is more suitable for distributing work to multiple handlers, or distributing one event to multiple recipients via producer/consumer or publish/subscribe patterns. A typical candidate could be MSMQ, ApacheMQ or RabbitMQ

Although with RPC this can be achieved as well, it is much more complicated and involves more work as you are operating on a somewhat lower abstraction level. RPCs shine when you need more the request/response style and value performance higher than the comfort of an MQ.

On top of MQ systems there are more sophisticated **Service Bus** systems, like for example NServiceBus. A service bus operates on an even higher level of abstraction. They also have their pro's and con's, but can be helpful too. At the end, it depends on your use case.

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>Disclaimer: I am actively involved in that project.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I can just suggest you to look at [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/). It is probably the easiest language to learn distributed systems, since sending messages is built into the language and it is irrelevant for the language and command itself, if the message is sent within the same PC, LAN or through the internet to a different machine.